# Debugging a vb.net web site project - "Breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document"

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, debugging

I recently received a vb asp.net web site project that I want to debug.  The site uses .Net 4 so I've created a new site within IIS and created an app pool.  The site runs locally as I want so now I need to debug it.

I'm running VS2010 so I attached this to the W3WP.exe process associated with my newly created app pool, so far so good.  Problem is that when I insert a break point into any of the .aspx.vb pages I get the message "Breakpoint will not currently be hit.  No symbols have been loaded for this document" appearing next to the break point.

In order to try and get VS2010 to link up with the site in IIS I manually inserted an error using notepad into one of the .aspx.vb pages.  This upsets the page nicely in internet explorer but it is not causing VS2010 to debug the page.

I did not originally write this site and I can't talk to the original developer to understand the intricacies.  I've done some research on this problem and have found a number of people discussing this error, but each person has previously been able to debug their page and it stops for no reason, my case is different as I'm only able to debug the page by attaching VS to the IIS process.

Any pointers would be greatly received.

Comment: Try making sure the deployed copy and the actual source code are the same. I've had issues where if I made a tiny change without redeploying, I would get that warning messages.

Answer (score 0):

Insert the breakpoint in the debugging mode. You may be inserting the breakpoint before debugging. While debugging the application, open the Script explorer(which comes as Script documents in the Script explorer) which shows all currently running pages. Select the one from them which you want to debug and try to insert a debug point there.